# Can't edit /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max

Tags: permissions, sudo

Recently my wireless network has being stopping to transfer data from some irregular time intervals that vary from 30 seconds to 20 minutes, and every time I need to plug off and then on the wireless adapter.

Using ping (`ping 8.8.8.8`) to see what happens, and when data transfer stops I receive this message:

> ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

So I found out that a solution for this is to increase buffer size with this command:

```
sudo echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
```

Although I can't execute this command, when I hit enter I get this:

> bash: /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max: Permission denied

Trying the command without `sudo` or with `gksu` returns the same message. Through GEdit I can open `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` file, and opening as administrator it enables me to click the 'Save' button, although after changing the value and hitting the button it returns me this message:

> Could not create a temporary backup file while saving /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
>
> gedit could not backup the old copy of the file before saving the new
>   one. You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, but if an
>   error occurs while saving, you could lose the old copy of the file.
>   Save anyway?

And even clicking in the 'Save anyway' button it returns the very same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sudo` command does not write the data as root. Only executes echo as root.
Try

```
sudo -s -H
echo 83886080 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks, I tried to became root by typing `su` although it asks for my password and show me: `su: Authentication Failure` and I am sure the password is correct, why does `su` doesn't seem to work and `sudo -s -H` does?

Comment: That is essentially another question. The answer is that on most systems `sudo` is set up to ask for **your** password, where `su` always asks for the password of `root`. They use different mechanisms. `su` does not remember you authenticated after you exit, `sudo` does (for 5 minutes in most set ups).